# Cant find Pygame Module

Tags: python, pygame

I just started game developing in python with pygame and I have the following code:

```
bif="main_background.jpg"
mif="player_head.png"

import pygame, sys
from pygame.locals import *

pygame.init()
screen=pygame.display.set_mode((640,360),0,64)

background=pygame.image.load(bif).convert()
mouse_c=pygame.image.load(mif).convert_alpha()

while True:
    for event in pygame.event.get():
        if event.type == QUIT:
            pygame.quit()
            sys.exit()

    screen.blit(background, (0,0))

    x,y = pygame.mouse.get_pos()
    x -= mouse_c.get_width()/2
    y -= mouse_c.get_height()/2

    screen.blir(mouse_c,(x,y))

    pygame.display.update()
```

I get the following error in Python:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Eier/Documents/Code Developments/pygame.py", line 4, in <module>
    import pygame, sys
  File "C:/Users/Eier/Documents/Code Developments\pygame.py", line 5, in <module>
    from pygame.locals import *
ImportError: No module named locals
>>>
```

If someone knows how to make python find pygame please reply.

Thank you :)

Comment: Did you call your script `pygame.py`? If you do that, you won't be able to find the installed `pygame` package, because Python has no way of knowing that this time you mean the package instead of the script. If that's the problem, just rename your script to, say, `mygame.py`.

Comment: If that's not the problem… how did you install pygame? It should have been installed into the middle of your own code directory, and if it was, that's what you need to fix.

Comment: For reference, you can use the code block button when asking/editing your question to ensure code appears properly (like i did for your traceback).

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I'm about 83.4% sure that you named your script `pygame.py` (or possibly created another file with the same name in the same directory as your script).

If you do that, Python has no way of knowing what you want to load when you `import pygame`. It could be your script, it could be the installed package—they both have the same name.

What ends up happening is that `import pygame` imports your script, then `from pygame.locals import *` looks for a module called `locals` inside your script. Since your script is a script, and not a package, Python just gets confused and prints a confusing `ImportError`.

Python 3.x gives you some ways around this, but 2.x does not, and I'm guessing you're using 2.x.

So, the solution is:

- Rename your script to `mygame.py`.
- Delete any other files in the same directory as your script named `pygame.py`.

Comment: `83.4%` should be more like `93.7%` ;-)